# Complex numbers equivalence proof

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I stumbled upon this exercise and can't seem to have any fruitful attemps, or rather I can't put together missing links.

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ be different complex number such that $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$.
 Prove that these three statements are equivalent:

(i) $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are verteces of an equilateral triangle: $|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|=|z_3-z_1|$

(ii) $z_1 + z_2 +z_3 = 0$

(iii) $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are the solutions of an equation $z^3-c=0$, for $c \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

I know that I have to prove that (i) $\rightarrow$ (ii), (ii) $\rightarrow$ (iii) and (iii) $\rightarrow$ (i), and for (i) $\rightarrow$ (ii), I tried to prove that if $z_1 = re^{i\varphi}$, then $z_2 = re^{i(\varphi \pm \frac{2}{3} \pi )} $ and $z_3 = re^{i(\varphi \mp \frac{2}{3} \pi )} $, but I don't get anywhere and pure algebraic manipulations were way too messy.

I am curious of how a solution would look like, and any would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using brutal force?

Comment: @Misakov it's brute force.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should note that since $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$, all three numbers lie on a circle centered at the origin, and therefore $z_2 = e^{i\alpha}z_1$ and $z_3 = e^{i\beta}z_1$, for some $\alpha, \beta \in (-\pi;\pi]$.

**(i) $\rightarrow$ (ii):**

Assume that $|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|=|z_3-z_1|$.

Therefore, $|z_1-z_2|=|z_3-z_1|$, so $|z_1|\cdot|1-e^{i\alpha}|=|z_1|\cdot|1-e^{i\beta}|$ and thus $|1-e^{i\alpha}|=|1-e^{i\beta}|$. This implies that $$\cos^2{\alpha}-2\cos{\alpha}+1+\sin^2{\alpha} = \cos^2{\beta}-2\cos{\beta}+1+\sin^2{\beta} $$ and, since $\cos^2{x} + \sin^2{x} = 1 $, $\cos{\alpha} = \cos{\beta}$, so either $\alpha = \beta$ or $\alpha = -\beta$. Since $z_2$ and $z_3$ are different, $\alpha \neq \beta$, so $\alpha = -\beta$.

Now since $|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|$, $|1-e^{i\alpha}|=|e^{i\alpha}-e^{i\beta}| = | e^{i\alpha} - e^{-i\alpha}|$. After a few calculations (substituting $\sin^2{x}$ by $1-\cos^2{x}$ and $\sin^2{x}+\cos^2{x}$ by $1$), we can see that $\cos^2{\alpha} - \frac{1}{2}\cos{\alpha}-\frac{1}{2} = 0$, so either $\cos{\alpha} = 1$ or $\cos{\alpha} =-\frac{1}{2}$. We know that $z_1 \neq z_2$, so $\cos{\alpha} =-\frac{1}{2}$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\alpha > 0$, therefore $\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\beta = -\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Therefore, $$z_1+z_2+z_3=z_1(1+e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}+e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}) = z_1(1+2\cos{\frac{2\pi}{3}})=z_1(1-1)=0$$

**(ii) $\rightarrow$ (iii):**

Assume that $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$, so $1+e^{i\alpha} + e^{i\beta}=0$. Thus $1+ \cos{\alpha}+\cos{\beta} = 0$, and hence $\cos{\alpha},\cos{\beta} \leq 0$, because $\cos{\alpha}+\cos{\beta}$ would be greater than -1 else, since $-1 \leq \cos{x} \leq 1$. Therefore, $\alpha, \beta \in (-\pi;-\frac{\pi}{2}] \cup  [\frac{\pi}{2};\pi]$.

Since, also, $\sin{\alpha}+\sin{\beta} = 0$, we can conclude $\alpha = - \beta$, from $\sin{\alpha} = \sin{-\beta}$, so $\cos{\alpha} = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Following the same steps as in the first part, we arrive at the conclusion that $z_2=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}z_1$ and $z_3=e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}z_1$. Now let $c=z_1^3$. Then, since $z_1^3=z_2^3=z_3^3$(because $e^{2\pi}=1$), they are the solutions of the equation $z^3-c=0$.

**(iii) $\rightarrow$ (i):**

Assume that $z_1$,$z_2$,$z_3$ are the solutions of an equation $z^3-c=0$. Let $\rho e^{i\theta}$ be the polar form of c. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $z_1 = \sqrt[3]{\rho}e^{i \frac{\theta}{3}}$, $z_2=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}z_1$ and $z_3=e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}z_1$.

Thus $|z_1-z_2| = |z_1|\cdot|1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}| = |z_2|\cdot|1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}| = |z_2-z_3|$. Because $e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}= \overline{e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}}$, $|1-e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}|=|1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}|$, since $\Im{1}=0$. Hence, $$|z_2-z_3| = |z_1|\cdot |1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}| = |z_1| \cdot |1-e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{3}}| = |z_1-z_3|.$$ Therefore $$|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|=|z_3-z_1|.$$

**Conclusion:**

Therefore, we can conclude that if  $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are different complex numbers such that $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|$, these three statements are equivalent:

(i) $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are verteces of an equilateral triangle: $|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|=|z_3-z_1|$

(ii) $z_1 + z_2 +z_3 = 0$

(iii) $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are the solutions of an equation $z^3-c=0$, for $c \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

---

Answer (score 1):

You are going in the correct direction. Note that in order to clean up the notation, we define $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/3}$, and we can relabel the numbers so that $z_1=re^{i\theta}$, $z_2=re^{i\theta}\zeta=z_1\zeta$, and similarly $z_3=z_2\zeta^2$. Now we just need $z_1+z_2+z_3=0$, but this is $z_1+z_1\zeta+z_1\zeta^2=z_1(1+\zeta+\zeta^2)$, so now all we need to do is prove $1+\zeta+\zeta^2=0$.

### Hint

> What is $\zeta(1+\zeta+\zeta^2)$ equal to?

I'm not sure how clear that hint is, so just in case, here is another one:

### Hint 2

> If $x\ne 1$, and $xy=y$, then what is $y$?

### Edit:

To answer the question in comments,
the geometric proof is fine.

To be honest, I started trying to write an algebraic proof, then realized that there wasn't really any way to do one without ultimately referring to the geometry at some point since what makes the statement true is that the complex numbers form a plane rather than a 3 dimensional or four dimensional space where an equilateral triangle on the unit sphere would not necessarily have to be nicely centered about the origin.

Comment: Since $\zeta(1+\zeta+\zeta^2)z_1 = (1+\zeta+\zeta^2)z_1, \zeta \neq 1$ and $z_1 \neq 0$, $1+\zeta+\zeta^2 = 0$. Thank you very much! But how can I show that $z_1=re^{i\theta}$, $z_2=re^{i\theta}\zeta$, and $z_3=z_1\zeta^2$?

Comment: @Amjad, in your original post you have that $z_1=re^{i\varphi}$, and $z_2=re^{i(\varphi\pm \frac{2}{3}\pi)}$ etc. I rewrote these using $\theta=\varphi$ since I'm more used to writing that and then $z_2=re^{i\varphi}(e^{2\pi i/3})^{\pm 1}$ by exponential rules, and then this is $z_1\zeta^{\pm 1}$ by the notational definitions I made. Then note that if $z_2\ne z_1\zeta$, then $z_3=z_1\zeta$, so we can switch $z_2$ and $z_3$ in that case. Therefore we can assume $z_2=z_1\zeta$. The we know $z_3=z_1\zeta^{-1}$ similarly, but $\zeta^{-1}=\zeta^2$, so $z_3=z_1\zeta^2$ as desired.

Comment: I know that it was just a matter of notation; but how do we arrive there? Does it suffice to say that, because $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are the verteces of an equilateral triangle inside a circle centered at the origin, all three can be represented by one of them "shifted" by 120 and 240 degrees?

Comment: @Amjad Ok let me add to my post :)

Comment: Thank you for the effort! :)

Comment: @Amjad Sorry about the delay, I was thinking about it for a while then got called to dinner, the geometric proof is fine. My post is edited with an explanation.

Comment: In my new post, I have an algebraic proof of the fact that $z_2 = \zeta z_1$ and $z_3 = \bar \zeta z_1$

Answer (score 0):

$z1, z2, z3$ are spaced at 120 degree intervals around a circle in the complex plane, so
$$z_2 = z_1  e^{2\pi i/3}$$ and 
$$z_3 = z_1  e^{-2\pi i/3}$$ and 
$$z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = z_1 ( 1 + \cos 2\pi/3 + i \sin 2\pi/3 + \cos 2\pi/3 - i \sin 2\pi/3)$$
             $$= z_1 ( 1 - 1/2  + i \sin 2\pi/3 - 1/2 - i \sin 2\pi/3) = 0$$ also
$$z_2^3 = z_1^3 e^{(2\pi i/3)*3 } = z_1^3 e^{2\pi i} = z_1^3$$ and 
$$z_3^3 = z_1^3 e^{(-2\pi i/3)*3 } = z_1^3 e^{-2\pi i} = z_1^3$$ so 
$z^3 = c$ where $c = z_1^3$ and $z = z1$, $z2$ or $z3$

Comment: It can be generalized to an n-gon also..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First find the solutions of $z^3-c=0$,
for $z=\rho e^{i \theta}$ and $c$ real and $>0$.
Then you can easily prove iii)$\rightarrow$ i) and ii).

Comment: Thanks! I guess then $z_1 = \sqrt[3]{\rho}e^{i \frac{\theta}{3}}$, $z_2 = \sqrt[3]{\rho}e^{i \frac{\theta+2\pi}{3}}$, and $z_3 = \sqrt[3]{\rho}e^{i \frac{\theta+4\pi}{3}}$, so $\sqrt[3]{\rho}|1-e^{i \frac{2\pi}{3}}|=|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|=|z_3-z_1|$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=r$, then all three points lie on the origin-centred circle of radius $r$.
If $|z_1-z_2|=|z_2-z_3|=|z_3-z_1|$, then the triangle is equilateral and everything now follows easily from geometry.
Draw an accurate picture.